# actionscript: undefined public variables?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, undefined

I have a class like this..

```
public class Doc {
  public function Doc():void {}

  public var myVar:Boolean;
}
```

How can I know if the value held by myVar is default false, or someone has assigned false to it ?!? Isn't there an undefined state? How can I achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 5):

Make myVar a property and use another variable to check if it's been set explicitly.

```
public class Doc 
{
  public function Doc():void {}

  private var _myVar:Boolean;
  private var myVarSetExplicitly:Boolean = false;
  public function get myVar():Boolean
  {
    return _myVar;
  }
  public function set myVar(value:Boolean):void
  {
    myVarSetExplicitly = true;
    _myVar = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: the flex framework itself uses examples of this very concept to find out if a value has been changed.  This is the best answer. You should accept it as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't with a boolean, it defaults to false and false === false.

You'd could not strictly type the variable and then use a getter and setter to protect the type

```
public class Doc {
  private var _myVar;

  public function set myVar(value:Boolean){
    _myVar = value;
  }

  public function get myVar(){
    return _myVar;
  }
}
```

Now, when its not set myVar should === null, and you should only be able to set it to a boolean after that.

But it feels a bit hacky, and I wonder why you need to tell the difference.

Comment: I need this because the object gets created, populated (if partly) and then sent as XML. But if a var hasn't been set I don't want it to be sent at all in the xml.

Comment: no this is a mess!! Can you suggest me something different to achieve my goal? point is some fields can be NULL in the database and they are only if I don't send them.. (backend is rails)

Comment: How is this a mess? Getters and setters are pretty standard and would allow you do do what you want... the Doc.myVar would default to null and then can only be set to a boolean, which to me sounds like exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: whould I ignore the compiler warnings? it says no return type given for the getter and no type given to _myVar..
I don't like warnings they're ugly =)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, we had to remove the strict typing to be able to do what you wanted, so I'm afraid you'll have to ignore them.

Comment: Be aware that you lose some performance by not using the strict typing.

Comment: You can get rid of compiler warnings by typing as Object (which will allow you to support null) or * (which supports everything Object does, plus undefined).

Comment: Avoid not typing variables at all costs.  You lose all compiler help and it has negative performance costs.  Amarghosh's answer is what you should do.